# DBVisualizer Fails to Connect

Tags: database, sybase, dbvisualizer

I am trying to Connect to Sybase Database (on VM Server) using Sybase SQL Anywhere (JConnect) Driver but everytime it fails with following error:

Product:  DbVisualizer Free 9.1.2
Build:  #2072 (2013/10/28 18:25)
Java VM:  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java Version:  1.6.0_21
Java Vendor:  Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS Name:  Windows 7
OS Arch:  amd64
OS Version:  6.1

An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
JZ00L: Login failed. Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLException
   SQL State: JZ00L

1) Nested Exception:

Long Message:
**SQL Anywhere Error -102: Database server connection limit exceeded**

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLWarning
   Error Code: 1601
   SQL State: 01W03

2) Nested Exception:

Long Message:
SQL Anywhere Error -102: Database server connection limit exceeded

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLWarning
   Error Code: 1601
   SQL State: 01W03

**Surprising part is my other colleagues tries to connect from their machine then its allowing but for some reason from my machine its not allowing. One more thing I observed is if I try again after 2-3 days it works fine without any changes in configuration.**

I have also verified following stuff:
DB Server is running fine
Restarted my machine many times
Restarted DB Visualizer

DB Visualizer Version: 9.1.2 (Freeware)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also verified Connection parameters (username, password, server IP, Port)

Comment: Have you googled what the following mean and how to solve it? > SQL Anywhere Error -102: Database server connection limit exceeded

Comment: Yes I checked various options people have suggested like some times it happens of Cherset issue, sometime because of old driver etc. None worked so far

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you ever get an solution, or did it just start working for no reason?

Comment: @horriblyUnpythonic after so much effort I could detect that some reason my previous connections were in zombie state and slowly one by one I kept on creating new connections. I logged into machine and killed them manually, it worked after that.

Comment: My issue was different, but reported a similar error. The computer I was attempting to connect to was running dbeng as opposed to dbsrv.