# DBVisualizer doesn't connect to SQL Server using jTDS

Tags: sql-server, dbvisualizer

I tried to connect my database using the default Sql Server driver and it doesn't work, but from my computer with the same configuration I can connect to the Management Studio.

> The error is time out, it can't find the database, but the
>   configuration is correct!

[image: Connection]

Comment: Posting the config screen is not very helpful, is difficult to say if something is wrong there. It would be more helpful to provide the specific SQL error code or the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give some more information than that would be helpful, Do you have installed correct (JDBC) driver btw? Also, see this link if it is helpful to you [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392397/dbvisualizer-fails-to-connect?rq=1)